# Is it a bad idea to implement my own Selection system for a recyclerView instead of using androidx.recyclerview.selection?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

For me, androidx.recyclerview.selection, is a very complex implementation for selecting recyclerview items, also, I do not need all of its features, that is why I thought of making my own selection system based on adding a boolean isSelected variable on my ItemModel and check if that item is selected.
Is this a bad idea? What would you recommend me?